# Clicking an <img> preventing the activation of the <a>

Tags: javascript, image, event-handling, dom-events, bookmarklet

I'm trying to implement a bookmarklet where the user will click one `<img/>` and will be redirected to another page where he will annotate the image.

If the image is inserted within a HTML anchor:

```
<a href="http://anywhere.org"><img src=""http://anywhere.org/image.png"/></a>,
```

Can I prevent the anchor to be activated? I tried

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

and/or

```
event.preventDefault();
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Please show us how you're using it.

Comment: as there are two questions, I will split my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can check if the event can be cancelated or not using:

```
var bool = event.cancelable;
```

And you can always try the classic

```
return false:
```

That will pretty much stop it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use event.cancelBubble and return false (for IE).

But your method works fine in FF.

```
  var stop = function(evt)   {
     evt = evt || window.event;


     if(typeof(evt.stopPropagation) === "function") {
        evt.stopPropagation();
     }

     if(typeof(evt.preventDefault) === "function")   {
        evt.preventDefault();
     }

     // this is for IE6
     evt.cancelBubble = true;         
     return false;
  };
```